# getting issue with AsyncImageView image on table view

Tags: ios

I am using `AsyncImageView` to load image on a `TableView` from the URL. Its works properly when the table load for the first time but issue comes when I scroll the `TableView` there are some cells which do not contain image so there I make the image alpha to 0 , but before that the cell show me the previous image for some split of time how to handle that can any one suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

try SDWebimage framework [here](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/tree/master/SDWebImage) . It contains a place holder image option , to show an loading image till the actual image gets downloaded